# Communication between Android web socket server with remote web socket client

Tags: javascript, android, html, java-websocket

I am working with web socket client in Android device, Able to communicating to a remote web socket server. But right now I want run web socket server on android device & I need connect it from a remote web socket client (like on the system browser). I tried by giving my android device's IP address on the remote client. But it showing following error.
"[Error] WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused"

Comment: "I tried by giving my android device's IP address on the remote client" -- what "remote client"? Is "the system browser" referring to a browser on the Android device, or a browser somewhere else?

Comment: I am using browser on my mac  as a remote client and am trying to create web socket client with my android device IP address.

Comment: Finally  I found the solution myself. Instead of passing localhost to the web socket server on my android device, I am passing my device  ip address and some port number, for remote client I did connect with same ip address and port number. I  am able to get the web socket connection.